# How to migrate Watch app to SwiftUI Lifecycle

Tags: swift, swiftui, watchkit, apple-watch, lifecycle

I have an iOS app with a Apple Watch extension. I downloaded Xcode 14 and have the warning:

> WatchKit storyboards are deprecated in watchOS 7.0 and later. Please migrate to SwiftUI and the SwiftUI Lifecycle.

I'm all for this migration, in fact, my initial hosting controller returns a SwiftUI view. But I can't find anywhere how to actually migrate to a SwiftUI Lifecycle from WatchKit. **Does anyone know how to do this?**

I'm completely fine with deleting my WatchKit storyboards since their unused other than pointing to the initial controller. Here's my initial controller code if it helps:

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class HostingController: WKHostingController<AnyView> {
    override var body: AnyView {
        return AnyView(WatchHomeUI())
    }
}
```

Comment: Créate a new Xcode project and make sure you start matching the app delegate, the YourAppApp file with the main wrapper and the info.plist

Answer (score 3):

You can simply replace the following files:

- Interface.strings
- Interface.storyboard
- HostingerController.swift

by

- YourWatchAppTargetName.swift
  with something like this as content:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct YourWatchAppTargetName: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

and don't forget to remove `@main` from your `ExtensionDelegate.swift` file.